# R copying attributes over to anther object

Tags: r

I have an initial variable:

```
a = c(1,2,3)
attr(a,'name') <- 'numbers'
```

Now I want to create a new variable that is a subset of `a` and then have it have the same attributes as `a`. Is there like a `copy.over.attr` function or something around that does this without me having to go inside and identify which one is user defined attributes etc. This gets complicated when I have numerous attributes attached to a single variable.

Comment: Have you looked into `mostattributes<-`?  If you have a list of possible attributes, it will attempt to assign them and keep going if it can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be used with caution and care. There is `mostattributes<-`, which receives a list and attempts to set the attributes in the list to the object in its argument.  At the very least, reading the source code will give you some nice ideas on how to check attributes between objects.  Here's a little run on your sample `a` vector.  It succeeds since it's not violating any properties of `b`

```
a = c(1,2,3)
attr(a,'name') <- 'numbers'

b <- a[-1]
attributes(b)
# NULL
mostattributes(b) <- attributes(a)
attributes(b)
# $name
# [1] "numbers"
```

Here's a sample of the source code where names are checked.

```
    if (h.nam <- !is.na(inam <- match("names", names(value)))) {
        n1 <- value[[inam]]
        value <- value[-inam]
    }
    if (h.dim <- !is.na(idin <- match("dim", names(value)))) {
        d1 <- value[[idin]]
        value <- value[-idin]
    }
    if (h.dmn <- !is.na(idmn <- match("dimnames", names(value)))) {
        dn1 <- value[[idmn]]
        value <- value[-idmn]
    }
    attributes(obj) <- value
```

There is also `attr.all.equal`. It's not the operation you want, but I think you would benefit from reading that source code too.  There are many good checks you can learn about in that one.

Comment: This seems like a very uncommon case, when `<-` and `=` are unequivalent. It seems that `mostattributes(b) = attributes(a)` fails.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a simple `attributes(b) <- attributes(a)` work?
This will just be executed after creating `b` from a subset of the data in `a`, so it's not really a single statement, but should work.

Comment: shouldn't work if there are user defined attributes in `a` and `b` has no attributes but the native ones

Comment: Pretty dangerous.  What about `row.names`, `col.names`, and `dim` for starters. Those are all likely to be different after subsetting

Comment: This is an okay solution for subset operation.