# Assign to variable _AND_ keep attributes

Tags: r

I have a variable with a huge matrix; this variable has some attributes, including smaller matrices.

I want to assign something small (like `NA`) to this variable, so that I can save memory; but I want to keep the attributes.

Is there some elegant way or do I have to do it in some clumsy way with two assignments, second one with [mostattributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27736187/684229)?

PS: illustrative example

```
a <- matrix(1:9,3,3)

attr(a, 'ahoj') <- 1:10

a <- NA # attributes lost, I want assignment which keeps them
```

The only thing I can think of is to replace the assignment with these 3:

```
empty_a <- NA
mostattributes(empty_a) <- attributes(a)
a <- empty_a
```

but that's pretty clumsy way :)

Comment: So your goal is to have a with just one NA and the attributes you defined?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the values of the object without losing all of the attributes and such, then you can use `[<-` (though this does preserve its dimensions):

```r
a <- matrix(1:9,3,3)
attr(a, 'ahoj') <- 1:10

a[] <- NA
a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA
# attr(,"ahoj")
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

Alternative, that does your `mostattributes`-like operation, with "some" smarts:

```r
copyattributes <- function(x, oldvalue = NULL, remattr = character(0)) {
  oldattr <- attributes(oldvalue)
  clsfun <- class(oldvalue)[1]
  remattr <- unique(c(
    remattr,
    if (exists(clsfun, mode = "function")) {
      names(attributes(match.fun(clsfun)()))
    } else character(0)))
  copyattr <- setdiff(setdiff(names(oldattr), remattr), names(attributes(x)))
  attributes(x) <- c(attributes(x), oldattr[ copyattr ])
  x
}

a <- matrix(1:9,3,3)
attr(a, 'ahoj') <- 1:10
b <- NA
attr(b, "quux") <- "A"
a <- copyattributes(b, a)
a
# [1] NA
# attr(,"quux")
# [1] "A"
# attr(,"ahoj")
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

The `remattr` tries to use the `class` of the old object (`a`) to determine what attributes are always there (e.g., `"dim"` for matrices, and `c("names", "row.names")` for frames), and *not* copy those over. Then it ensures it does not overwrite or delete existing attributes.